# Python subproces.call not working as expected

Tags: python, subprocess

I can not get the subprocess.call() to work properly:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(['adduser', '--home=/var/www/myusername/', '--gecos', 'GECOS', '--disabled-login', 'myusername'], shell=True)
adduser: Only one or two names allowed.
1
```

But without shell=True:

```
>>> call(['adduser', '--home=/var/www/myusername/', '--gecos', 'GECOS', '--disabled-login', 'myusername'])
Adding user `myusername' ...
Adding new group `myusername' (1001) ...
Adding new user `myusername' (1001) with group `myusername' ...
Creating home directory `/var/www/myusername/' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
0
```

Or the same directly in shell:

```
root@www1:~# adduser --home=/var/www/myusername/ --gecos GECOS --disabled-login myusername
Adding user `myusername' ...
Adding new group `myusername' (1001) ...
Adding new user `myusername' (1001) with group `myusername' ...
Creating home directory `/var/www/myusername/' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
```

I miss some logic in the shell=True behavior. Can somebody explain me why? What is wrong with the first example? From the adduser command error message it seems that arguments are somehow crippled.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use `shell=True` when it works without it? Do not open security holes in your program without need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify shell=True you switch to quite different behaviour. From the docs:

> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])

So you are running the equivalent of

```
/bin/sh -c "adduser" --home=/var/www/myusername/ --gecos GECOS --disabled-login myusername
```

The error message you are getting is what happens when you try and run `adduser` without any arguments as all the arguments are being passed to `sh`.

If you want to set shell=True then you would need to call it like this:

```
call('adduser --home=/var/www/myusername/ --gecos GECOS --disabled-login myusername', shell=True)
```

OR like this:

```
call(['adduser --home=/var/www/myusername/ --gecos GECOS --disabled-login myusername'], shell=True)
```

But mostly you just want to use `call` without the `shell=True` and use a list of arguments.    As per your second, working, example.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about this but I think that it you specify `Shell=True`, you should be passing the command line as a single string which the shell itself will interpret:

```
>>> call('adduser --home=/var/www/myusername/ --gecos GECOS --disabled-login myusername', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with `shell=True` you need to pass string into `args` rather than list of arguments.

A simple test:

```
In [4]: subprocess.call(['echo', 'foo', 'bar'], shell=True)

Out[4]: 0

In [5]: subprocess.call('echo foo bar', shell=True)
foo bar
Out[5]: 0
```

I.e. `echo` got the right arguments only when I used string, not list.

Python version 2.7.3

Comment: You can use an list... but the first argument to the list must be the complete command you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

If shell is True the specified command will be executed through the shell, that is the shell takes care of filename wildcards, environment variable expansion etc. When you use shell=True the cmd is a single string, it must be formatted exactly as it would be typed in the shell.  If shell=True and cmd is a sequence, the first argument specifies the command and the additional arguments are treated as arguments to the shell itself (by the `-c` switch).

If shell=False, and a sequence of arguments is provided the module will take care of properly escaping and quoting the arguments and for example `~` won't be expanded as the home directory etc.

Read more about it in the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) documentation, and mind the security hazard related to shell=True.

Comment: cmd doesn't have to be a single string, it can be an iterable. But if it is an iterable the first element is sent to the shell as the argument to `-c`. The rest are arguments for the shell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!  I missed this so far :), but now I edited my answer accordingly.